# How to install Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, wcf

I deleted the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service with **sc delete** command, now when I try to install **Application Server Role**, it give me the following error:

> Attempt to install TCP Port Sharing
>   failed with error code 0x80070404. The
>   specified service does not exist as an
>   installed service.

How to solve this? Re-install Windows Server 2008 is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 is included  Windows Server 2008 R2, and .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 is a subcomponent foundation layer of .NET Framework 3.5.1.

To get Net.Tcp back on a machine with this framework release, run ServiceModelReg.exe. See somewhat detailed instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx).

The crucial part is this:

"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -i -enable
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r

The "-r" option in ServiceModelReg reinstalls WCF scriptmaps and services on the machine. See "ServiceModelReg.exe /?" for all the options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: life saver man .. I struggled through this for almost one and half days. Some how my tcp port sharing service was screwed up ..

Comment: If you have 64-bit machine, you'll need to run the 64-bit version of ServiceModelReg.exe: "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r  (Note the **64** in Framework64)

Answer (score -1):

1. From the Start menu, open the Services Management Console either by opening a Command Prompt window and typing **services.msc** or by opening Run and typing **services.msc** into the Open box.
2. In the Name column of the list of services, **right-click the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service**, and select **Properties** from the menu.
3. To enable the manual **start-up of the service**, in the Properties window select the General tab, and in the Startup type box select Manual, and then click Apply.
4. To start the service, in the Service status area, click the Start button. The service status should now display **"Started".**
5. To return to the list of services, **click the OK**, and exit the MMC Console.

Comment: down vote because If the service is not installed, it won't be in the services list.